# What kind of data types are best to work with prediction algorithms of R

Tags: r, regression, classification

Assuming the data is tidy and it has a mix of columns of type numeric, character and Factor. What is the data type that would give best results when using different prediction techniques in R?

I am guessing the preferred data type would differ based on prediction method like:

1. A regression model would require columns to be in numeric type. But what about the columns which are non-numeric ? What should they be to get the best out of the algorithm ?
2. Similarly what type of columns would give best results in a classification problem ?

Comment: This is completely dependent on the statistical model or algorithm you want to use. As it's written, this question is probably too broad to solicit useful answers.

Comment: I fully agree with @DLDahly. However, it could be useful to see a brief answer that points out the basic misunderstandings about data types and prediction algorithms upon which this question is predicated.